# WTelegramClient How to apply proxy settings?

Tags: telegram-api, wtelegramclient

An application was written using the WTelegramClient library. There was a task to use the proxy server settings to connect to the Internet:
Address,
Port,
Username,
Password.

Now the connection is made without a proxy.
We declare variables:

```
using TL;

private WTelegram.Client _client;
private User _user;
private TelegramSettings telegramSettings = null;
```

We fill it with values:

```
private void saveSettingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (telegramSettings == null) telegramSettings = new TelegramSettings();
    telegramSettings.UseProxy = checkEditUseProxy.Checked;
    telegramSettings.ProxyHost = textEditProxyHost.Text.Trim();
    telegramSettings.ProxyPort = textEditProxyPort.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(textEditProxyPort.Text.Trim());
    telegramSettings.ProxyUserName = textEditProxyUserName.Text.Trim();
    telegramSettings.ProxyPassword = textEditProxyPassword.Text.Trim();
    telegramSettings.PhoneNumber = (string)textBoxPhone.EditValue;
    telegramSettings.API_Hash = textBoxApiHash.Text.Trim();
    telegramSettings.API_ID = textBoxApiID.Text.Trim();
}
```

Making changes to the Сonfig:

```
string Config(string what)
{
    switch (what)
    {
        case "api_id": return telegramSettings.API_ID;
        case "api_hash": return telegramSettings.API_Hash;
        case "phone_number": return telegramSettings.PhoneNumber;
        case "verification_code":
        case "password":        // if user has enabled 2FA
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CodeNeeded(what.Replace('_', ' '))));
            _codeReady.Reset();
            _codeReady.Wait();
            return textBoxCode.Text;
        case "first_name":
        case "last_name":
            return null;        // if sign-up is required
        default: return null;
    };
}
```

Connecting

```
_client = new WTelegram.Client(Config);
_user = await _client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
```

**How to apply proxy settings?**

Answer (score 3):

Using a proxy with WTelegramClient is described in the [Examples documentation](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#proxy):

Set TcpHandler before login:

```cs
    client.TcpHandler = async (address, port) =>
    {
        var proxy = new Socks5ProxyClient(ProxyHost, ProxyPort, ProxyUsername, ProxyPassword);
        return proxy.CreateConnection(address, port);
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer and link to the documentation.

Comment: You need the NuGet package `StarkSoftProxy` installed for that. Also don't forget `using Starksoft.Net.Proxy;` at the top